# pip install "numpy" causing error in android chaquopy

Tags: android, android-studio, pip, chaquopy

Hi I've been trying to use chaquopy to run my python script but I've been having a trouble in import part. It works fine when I run a script that doesn't require any external library and don't use install code that you would write in build.gradle.

```
        python{
            pip{
                install "numpy"
            }
        }
```

The problem comes in as soon as I slip that install code in. It comes up with the error message written below.

```
> Task :app:generateDebugPythonRequirements
C:\Users\q\AndroidStudioProjects\Chaquopy_Practice\app\build\generated\python\bp.zip\pip\_vendor\ipaddress.py:1106: SyntaxWarning: 'str' object is not callable; perhaps you missed a comma?
C:\Users\q\AndroidStudioProjects\Chaquopy_Practice\app\build\generated\python\bp.zip\pip\_vendor\ipaddress.py:1106: SyntaxWarning: 'str' object is not callable; perhaps you missed a comma?
Chaquopy: Installing for armeabi-v7a
C:\Users\q\AndroidStudioProjects\Chaquopy_Practice\app\build\generated\python\bp.zip\pip\_vendor\ipaddress.py:1106: SyntaxWarning: 'str' object is not callable; perhaps you missed a comma?
C:\Users\q\AndroidStudioProjects\Chaquopy_Practice\app\build\generated\python\bp.zip\pip\_vendor\ipaddress.py:1106: SyntaxWarning: 'str' object is not callable; perhaps you missed a comma?
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://chaquo.com/pypi-7.0
Collecting numpy
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/numpy/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/numpy/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/numpy/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /pypi-7.0/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /pypi-7.0/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /pypi-7.0/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /pypi-7.0/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /pypi-7.0/numpy/
  Could not fetch URL https://chaquo.com/pypi-7.0/numpy/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='chaquo.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pypi-7.0/numpy/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for numpy
Chaquopy: Exit status 1
```

I think SSLError happened to some other people but I couldn't find what SyntaxWarning: 'str' object ~~ is about.

Comment: The SyntaxWarning was caused by an old version of pip (https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7615): we'll fix this in the next version of Chaquopy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem itself wasn't in the pip install command.
The real problem came from using python.exe from anaconda instead of original python.exe.
I was able to solve the issue after downloading python 3.8.6 and changing buildpython path.

Comment: How did you use the buildpython??
it is not working for me::::

              python {
            buildPython "C:/Program Files/Python39"
            pip {
                install "numpy"
            }
        }

Comment: @ParthaPaul: `buildPython` should be the path to the actual python executable, not the directory that contains it.